# A Deceitful Rebus

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus

I am thinking of an image. Using Photoshop, paint, or your favorite image editor, create and post the image I am thinking of (any reasonable logical equivalent).

To ensure this post isn’t flooded with a hundred pictures of cats, here are some clues:

1. Your image should contain an English phrase, including a word beginning with ‘r’.
2. Your image should contain the following rebus. You may shrink this to make it fit, it does not need to be legible.

[image: what is this]

3. As part of your post, please mention the solution to the rebus provided in (2).  This is to help others understand the puzzle’s solution. I am ultimately looking for a 4 word (not longer) phrase starting with ‘T’. Your image should align with the theme of the rebus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The image in the background of the rebus is

> Child with a Dove by Pablo Picasso

The solution to the rebus is

> Ceci n'est pas une pipe

Because

> ICE (backwards), NEST, letters 1 and 2 from PAblo, SUN, and a | (PIPE) symbol (backwards). I'm not sure where the C on the start and the E on the end are supposed to come from though. OP note: the main part is nested between the top and bottom of ChildwithadovE.

which is the text found in

> the famous painting "The Treachery of Images" by Rene Magritte.

I think the final answer (a four word phrase starting with T) is

> The Treachery of Images

So my answer is:

> [image: this image]

Comment: Lbh sbhaq gur qrprvgshy cvcr! Abj pna lbh perngr n qrprvgshy erohf? Whfg na vzntr cyhf svir jbeqf. V unq znqr zl bja ohg vg jnf fb sha V qryrgrq vg naq vapbecbengrq vg vagb gur chmmyr nf n punyyratr vafgrnq. Lbh pna rira fvta vg : )

Comment: Also see here for reasoning of C E: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110207/around-the-world-to-a-mystery-country

Comment: You got it. Great painting!