# Winter Rebus? (W in box)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

The answer is a phrase. (1 9 6 2 1 4 5) … *(10 1 7)*

Please provide an explanation justifying your answer. No computer needed.

[image: Square with a letter... see text version, too much to type here]

*Text Version of the image:*
<sub>Across the top of the image is a single word: “What?”.

Beneath is a white square, outlined in as faint possible, with no distinguishing features. The letter W’s displayed in the center of it, fading from L to R.  It may possibly be an inverted “M”.

Outside the square is a field of white.</sub>

Hint 1:

> Step one (lateral thinking portion): recognize what the question mark in the title and tags (or lack thereof) are telling you... [(it's more like a drawing)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110531/a-deceitful-rebus/110538#110538)

Hint 2:

> If you are staring at the "W in box" trying to guess what the op is thinking, you are in for a long winter. The solution is simpler than that.

Hint 3:

> A computer could solve this but it'd be a pretty trivial program, with two inputs and one output.

Hint 4:

> "as faint possible"? Shouldn't it be "as faint as possible", or even better, "faintly"? And why did the op bother telling us that a W looks like an inverted M?

Hint 5: (help narrow your focus as this seems to be stumping people)

> Is this a rebus?
>  - No, see Hint 1. So there is no 'underneath a heading' or 'in a box'. You might call it an abstract drawing? Feel free to block imgur with your firewall if you keep finding yourself staring at it.
>  Are there ellipses in the answer?
>  - No. The enumeration given is not "(1 9 6 2 1 4 5... 10 1 7)".
>  So what's with the last three numbers?
>  - Feel free to ignore them if they are stressing you out. Eventually they will find you.
>  So what is it?
>  - The title and last line give some strong hints. See if you can guess a word or two... and then *prove* they are correct.

Hint 6:

> There is nothing special about the W. I could have drawn any other letter or skipped it entirely.   And no, 'letter' is not in the answer.

Hint 7:

> @mohirl is partially correct. Search the entire puzzle very carefully to prove it.  Some things are more than they seem.

Comment: Well, I keep looking, but all I'm seeing is rot13(N QBHOYRLBH SENZRQ OL N TERL FUNCR... HAQREARNGU N URNQVAT (1 9 6 2 1 4 5) … (10 1 7))

Comment: @stiv maybe think of this as a low difficulty enigmatic vs. a high difficulty rebus

Comment: Once in a while I come back to stare at this question when I'm not feeling confused enough in my day-to-day life.  I really hope someone figures this one out soon, it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Based purely on the date of posting and the letter counts, I'm seeing something like rot13(N Puevfgznf [fbzrguvat.. yrggre?] va n fabj svryq/fgbez...[fbzrguvat] n cerfrag (va n obk)). But I've no justification whatsoever.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Possibly partial answer, with help from Mohirl's comment:

The enumerated answer starts with:

> **A crossword square in a snow storm**
>
>  Not sure if I'm meant to find more words for the (10, 1, 7), or if it's just there to get the answer (detailed below).

> Ignoring the image completely, and just using the text description. If we use the given counts to select words we get:
>  1 - **Across**
>  9 - the top of the image is a single **word**:
>  6 - "What?". Beneath is a white **square**,
>  2 - outlined **in**
>  1 - **as**
>  4 - faint possible, with **no**
>  5 - distinguishing features. The letter **W's**
>  ...
>  10 - displayed in the center of it, fading from L **to**
>  1 - **R**.
>  7 - It may possibly be an inverted "**M**". Outside the square is a field of white.
>
>   Taking all the highlighted words/letters and respacing to fit the (first part of the) enumeration gives us "A crossword square in a snow storm"

Comment: Great job! Yes, the second italicized set continues the pattern but not the enumeration, as you have it.

Comment: Thank you @fijx!  And thank you @Amoz, I knew I could trust the solution would be fair and clear. Great solve and great puzzle

Answer (score -1):

> Ghost by FogHat

Explanation

> There is an youtube music called Ghost by FogHat.
>  First letter W has shadow. Rest portion doesnt have shadow, ghosts dont have shadow. So rest portion is Ghost.
>  The HAT is ghost
>  Fog is making the shadow W blurry.
>  Question mark resemble S; a letter in Ghost
>  Question mark in "Gothic" font remembers G and O.
>  All letters of G, H, O, S and T can be found.

Comment: But what about the letter counts (1 9 6 2 1 4 5) … (10 1 7)

Comment: Hmmm... Sorry, I'm not convinced many of the statements here make much logical sense... It's all *very* speculative: 'ghosts dont have shadow', 'The HAT is ghost'...? Does this answer really explain any of the hints laid in the puzzle, including the letter counts and spoilered hints?